# Delete a duplicate widget in appJar

Tags: python, python-3.x

how can I delete a duplicate widget in appJar?

i get this error

```
appJar.appjar.ItemLookupError: Duplicate widgetName: my_label_name
```

I want to delete the widget(actually a label) to make another one, but with the same name

I can't figure it out how I tried with removeWidgetType but it doesn't seem to work? did I pass good arguments into the removeWidgetType

```
for line in chatlog:
                print(line)

                saved_line = line
                chatlog.truncate(0)

                app.removeWidgetType('Label', 'chatline')
                app.addLabel('chatline', saved_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the line `app.removeWidgetType(...)`

That function relies on the first parameter being a number, in this case it would be 0 for a Label. This is a wrapper function used by all the specific widget removal functions.

You should be using:

`app.removeLabel('chatLine')`

That will then call the function you're using, passing the correct number identifier.

See here for some more details: http://appjar.info/pythonWidgetOptions/#widget-manipulation